# Gradle Incremental Build not generate folder structure in target path

Tags: java, gradle, build, incremental-build

Gradle Incremental Build task detect changed files from the project and compile and put only those files into target directory.

Problem is that when it's put those change files into target directory but it doesn't make package.

Eg: Suppose i have package 'org/example/test.java' when i run task using gradle and it's detect that test.java file change then it's compile and put into target directory like: 
'target/project/WEB-INF/classes/test.class' not make any package.
But i need 'target/project/WEB-INF/classes/org/example/test.class'

Any help appreciated. I put my gradle task code below:

```
task incrementalReverse(type: IncrementalReverseTask) {
    inputDir = file('src/java')
    outputDir = file("${tempBuildPath}/WEB-INF/classes")
}


class IncrementalReverseTask extends DefaultTask {

@InputDirectory
def File inputDir

@OutputDirectory
def File outputDir

@TaskAction
void execute(IncrementalTaskInputs inputs) {
    println inputs.incremental ? "CHANGED inputs considered out of date"
                               : "ALL inputs considered out of date"
    if (!inputs.incremental)
        project.delete(outputDir.listFiles())

    inputs.outOfDate { change ->
        println "out of date: ${change.file.name}"
        def targetFile = new File(outputDir, change.file.name)
        targetFile.text = change.file.text.reverse()
    }

    inputs.removed { change ->
        println "removed: ${change.file.name}"
        def targetFile = new File(outputDir, change.file.name)
        targetFile.delete()
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def targetFile = new File(outputDir, change.file.name)
targetFile.parentFile.mkdirs()
```

Comment: <sarcastic>Brilliant feedback</sarcastic>